# OpenSMTPD: MX lookup for relay host

Tags: networking, dns, smtp

I'm trying to figure how opensmtpd can be used to relay email using a specific host, which should be figured with an MX lookup.

Let's say that i have my MX record for `internaldomain.server.lan`.

This `internaldomain.server.lan` contains 3 different `A` records.

I would like that opensmtpd will use `internaldomain.server.lan` for ANY emails. The email servers running on the various  `internaldomain.server.lan` A records will be able to relay the emails.

Basically, what I configure in `relay` must be resolved via `MX`, not with `A` record, in order to exploit redundancy.